# Does channel.close() actually stop scheduled tasks by channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate()?

Tags: tcp, netty

I am developing a device control program (Tcp Server) using Netty.

I have to send status request message every 1 second, Therefor I am using the method `channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate()` and it works fine.

```
channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate( () -> {
         channel.writeAndFlush("REQ MSG"); 
         System.out.println("REQ MSG"); 
}, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

and when I call `channel.close()`, the above scheduled task is automatically stopped.

But when I eliminate `channel.writeAndFlush()` and call `channel.close()`, the above scheduled task is not stopped.

```
channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate( () -> {
         // channel.writeAndFlush("REQ MSG"); 
         System.out.println("REQ MSG"); 
}, 1000, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference... In both cases you need to explicit cancel the task via `future.cancel()` once you want to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also think so and I applied future.cancel(). That way, there are no problems at all. However, it is true that such differences do exist in my case. So I just left a question to see if there is anything I don't know about Netty thread model. I will find out more if there is a problem with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the exact cause in my case, and as I advised, I fixed it as follows.

```
private final CopyOnWriteArrayList<ScheduledFuture<?>> userTaskFutures = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

public void scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit) {
    ScheduledFuture<?> future = channel.eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period, unit);
    userTaskFutures.add(future);
}

public void disconnect() {
    ... 
    if (!userTaskFutures.isEmpty()) {
        userTaskFutures.forEach(future -> future.cancel(true));
        userTaskFutures.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same situation, my setup: websocket server. When new connection created I've creating ttl handler like this

```
channel.eventLoop().scheduleWithFixedDelay(
            TTLHandler(channel), 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS
        )
```

The code inside TTLHandler make internal logic and then try to drop expireded channel :

```
channel.deregister()
channel.disconnect()
channel.close()
```

None of this closing methods stopped `eventLoop()` and TTLHandler keep going.

My investigation lead me into `ScheduledFutureTask.java` where `DefaultPromise` checks cancellation by `isCancelled()` method `for CancellationException`

```
private static boolean isCancelled0(Object result) {
        return result instanceof CauseHolder && ((CauseHolder) result).cause instanceof CancellationException;
    }
```

so I directly added into my disconnect section additional

```
throw CancellationException()
```

and it works